# Can a Wifi driver bug have an impact on the rest of the system?

Tags: networking, drivers, freeze, 23.04

I have a almost fresh Asus UM5302 (Zenbook S 13 OLED) with Ubuntu 23.04. WiFi works fine most of the time, except on one access point at a friend's place.

When I connect to this access point (5GHz) :

- network is very slow (`iwconfig` shows a bit rate between 1 and 30Mb/s) and sometimes unusable (cannot open new connections)
- some weird freezes starts to appear in some apps on some seemingly uncorrelated but reproducible actions :

  - in Firefox, everytime I right-click, or try to open a website which needs access to webcam, it freezes and I have to force quit and restart
  - in Guake, everytime I right-click, or open a new tab with keyboard shortcuts, I have to force quit and restart

Other devices (my phone and other computers) works perfectly on this network. And if I don't connect to this network, system works perfectly (home and work Wifi are not a problem).

What could be the explanation ?